# Keeping id's without gaps - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails app, and it has route like this:

```
objects/id
```

But each object can be deleted.

So if first object (with id  = 1) was deleted,   objects/1 will be 404 - not found.

I want to keep it in such way, that if object with id = 1 was deleted, object with id = 2 becomes with id = 1, object 3 with id 2 and so on.

Is it possible? How can I do this?

Comment: That's a really, really, really bad idea, and antithetical to how Rails works. The object with id 3 should *always* have the id 3, that's the point of REST. You're invalidating every URL in your system each time a record is deleted. People might have links or bookmarks to those pages that are suddenly links to random *different* pages. If you delete a resource at a given URL, that URL **should** 404, not become some random different resource. There is no benefit to this, and many draw-backs. You absolutely should *not* do this.

Comment: you should NOT do this! there is no benefit to this. To the contrary, you would not be able to make any sense of your historical logs, or URLs.   The whole idea about IDs in activerecord is that they never change!

Comment: Thanks... that makes sence.

Answer (score 0):

Totally disagree with this approach. Think, if your model A has relationship with some other model B and model A changes the object ids, then you have to do the same with all referencing objects.

And what if you delete some object in middle of some transaction and deletion is committed and your transaction till referencing the same object id. That will be big trouble.

```
 obj1 = SomeModel.all.first    #id = 1

 obj2 = SomeModel.all.second   #id = 2
```

now destroy obj1

```
 obj1.destroy #now in database obj2 record's id becomes 1
```

but obj2 is till having id 2 (since not updated, remember `obj.reload`). when you try to save obj2; it will lead to inconsistent state.

So this is really impossible in rails to modify the id and even in some use case you do, will lead to large performance degrade.

Comment: Not really an issue with cascading foreign keys, the problem is when the ID is held in some remote system that updates can't possibly cascade to, like every single client's bookmarks.

Comment: That's sound great, but what if your data is modified by two different processes, like two different web requests and one of them is still in progress?

Comment: You'd need to do some aggressive locking. I'm not saying it's not a problem, I'm just saying that the *technologically insurmountable* problem is that all links into your site are broken by any given record's deletion.

Comment: I'm absolutely agree :)

Answer (score 0):

It can be done at *extraordinary* expense, and with the serious risk of completely screwing up everything. Renumbering things will also damage any bookmarks, making them point to the wrong records. Short answer: **DO NOT** do this.

As a rule: A database ID, once assigned, should not change. There's many good reasons for this, but the most important is that this ID will be referenced in many other tables, and all these references will have to be updated as well. Often there's no easy way to do this.

What you should be doing instead is coming up with a non-ID based system, such as using a slug instead. Rails supports routing to these natively:

```
def to_param
  self.slug
end
```

Now you can assign some kind of "slug" to each record that will appear in the URL, ending up with something like:

```
/users/bob
```

Exposing IDs in the URLs is always a somewhat less than ideal situation to start with as these may be revealing information that's not necessarily supposed to be public, and they also invite tampering to discover other records which may not be protected properly.